# My intellij plugin for xml completion not work on Intellij Ultimate version

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

It works perfect on Intellij Community Edition version.

like following

[image]

on Intellij Ultimate version

[image]

There is no recommadation from my plugin. my code never run on 
Ultimate version.

Here is my plugin configuration

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
<completion.contributor language="XML"
implementationClass="com.ccnode.codegenerator.view.MapperSqlCompletionContributor"/>
```

my plugin source code on https://github.com/gejun123456/MyBatisCodeHelper
How can i fix this probelm on Ultimate version?

Comment: It looks like Ultimate handles it via the language Injection and a different built-in plug-in. Does it help if you adjust the language injection settings to not use the bundled SQL support?

Comment: after unselect the iBatis3 language injection, it work just like Community Edition.
Is there anyway to make my plugin work with it together since many people might not want to adjust  language injection settings, thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that another plug-in has already implemented and registered the language injection for this specific code fragment and is used instead of your plug-in.

The first successful injection implementation will work, you can configure your `languageInjector` to either be the `first` or to be `before` another plug-in injector:

```
<languageInjector implementation="com.InjectorImpl" order="first"/>

<languageInjector implementation="com.InjectorImpl" order="before" id="other.injector.id"/>
```

Comment: is there any way that i can disable other plugin language injection.